# Running selenium tests in parralel (more than 2)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a project which uses selenium and testng. I tried selenium grid and managed to run tests in parallel.

However running more than 2 tests parallel is not efficient, in fact running 3 test cases in parallel on the same machine is slower due to slower network and maxed cpu. (Tried on google VMs).

Any one managed to run +3 test cases efficiently, if so any tips. I don't want to use more than a virtual machine at the current point due to cost.

Comment: I've run 4 parallel instances on my machine with no performance issues. It must be something to do with either the machine you are running it on or the way you are triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is not of Selenium but of the limited performance of the system you're running your tests on.

Selenium has a great way to handle this problem gracefully. You can run your scripts on remote machines. Yes, machines as in plural and it is all handled by selenium itself. To be precise, it is handled by [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp). To get started with selenium grid, you can click on the above link provided and that should really help with you.

As an added bonus, try reading about [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/). It has the advantage of easy scalability as per your needs and the ability to run your tests on virtually any device and browser available, with the ability of version control. And no, I don't work for them, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ,

The only way I can see out of this is making the tests smaller and make the amount of tests running in parallel smaller and spreading them out over a larger time scale.

I would advice maybe using one extra VM, the impact it would have would be beneficial.

As mentioned above is Selenium Grid which is excellent so I'll give another solution to you.

You can use Jenkins which can be used also.

In my environment I have a 4 jobs.

3 of these jobs are pointing to TestNG XML files to run whatever tests are specified in the file.

I then have another job which is known as a Build Flow job. This job points to the other 3 jobs and executes them, but executes them in parallel.

Compared to Selenium Grid I found it much more easier to implement . It also gives you more control ( I believe ) as you have an overview and control of each stage of your testing . Changes are also easy to make.

If you would like more details information just let me know and I can edit this answer and make it more of a " how-to" rather than an informative answer.

Also with Jenkins you can use a Master/Slave method which also lets you distribute workloads between VMs , which would be great if you could get your hands on another VM if resources allow.

At the moment I think the only solution to your problem the way is to allocate more memory/another VM or to just to reduce the amount of tests running in parallel and spread them out of multiple batches/runs but if your trying to match a certain time window ( which is something I had to do) it may not be suitable.

Comment: I guess using Jenkins is a great idea , but I stll think selenium should be able to provide a parallel solution which goes above 2 parralel tests. how do you manage to centralize reports coming from different jobs

Comment: Hey @jnam. You can get it to run above 2 parallel tests, you just speify in your build flow jobs the jobs you are running parallel. You must just make sure you have enough executors set in Jenkins. For reporting I'm using extent report as a listener so a report is generated for each of my XML files.